# Hibernate Envers @GeneratedValue skips values

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, hibernate-envers

I am working on a project with Hibernate and its Envers jar. I am also using Oracle 11g. It works fine except for one thing. When I give a `@Id` and `@GeneratedValue` to an `@Audited` entity say User and I insert new lines in my `USERS` table the id skips a value ( the ids should be like 3,4,5,6... but are 3,5,7,... ) and the `REV` column in the `USERS_AUD` table also skips sometimes. Probably, that's bacause the `ID` and `REV` fields in the `USERS_AUD` table cannot be equal ( an entity in that table cannot have the same id and revision number ). How can I modify this behavior so that the ids in my `USERS` table are generating normally ?

Comment: Please show us your code

Comment: Enver may only mean to have a `@Version`-Field. *_REV-Tables are more like "Hibernate Enver Auditions". Only Auditions are able to save old table-tuples. Anyway, this question is not related to Auditions or Enver i guess. I am happy to read that you use the technique anyway.